# Android button click to stop all music MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

**I want to make a stop button to stop all the media players at the same time**
and 
if possible make the media player to stop playing sound before playing the next sound. So the sounds won't go through each other.

the important thing is make a stop button to stop all the media players at the same time.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.harshalpanpaliya.saluchan;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer aapSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.upaar_wale_jab_upaar_bulana_tab);



        final Button playCatMeow = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upaar_wale_jab_upaar_bulana_tab);

        playCatMeow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aapSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }


        });
        final MediaPlayer bhopalSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bhopal);



        final Button bhopal = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bhopal);

        bhopal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bhopalSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        final MediaPlayer kamleshSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kamlesh);



        final Button kamlesh = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.kamlesh);

        kamlesh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                kamleshSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        final MediaPlayer bhag_keSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bhag_ke);



        final Button bhag_ke = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bhag_ke);

        bhag_ke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bhag_keSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer bhagke_remixSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bhagke_remix);

        final Button bhagke_remix = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bhagke_remix);

        bhagke_remix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bhagke_remixSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        final MediaPlayer dun_dun_dunSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dun_dun_dun);

        final Button dun_dun_dun = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.dun_dun_dun);

        dun_dun_dun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dun_dun_dunSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer how_to_use_saluchanSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.how_to_use_saluchan);

        final Button how_to_use_saluchan = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.how_to_use_saluchan);

        how_to_use_saluchan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                how_to_use_saluchanSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_naSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_na);

        final Button do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_na = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_nado_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_na);

        do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_na.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                do_teen_din_nahi_piya_tha_naSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer marjaungaSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.marjaunga);

        final Button marjaunga = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.marjaunga);

        marjaunga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                marjaungaSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer bindassSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bindass);

        final Button bindass = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bindass);

        bindass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bindassSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiyeMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiye);

        final Button aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiye = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiye);


        aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiye.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aap_bhi_laga_ke_dekhiyeMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer shuruwatSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shuruwat);

        final Button shuruwat = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.shuruwat);

        shuruwat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shuruwatSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer saluchanSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.saluchan);

        final Button saluchan = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.saluchan);

        saluchan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saluchanSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer bidi_pita_hoon_remixSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bidi_pita_hoon_remix);

        final Button bidi_pita_hoon_remix = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bidi_pita_hoon_remix);

        bidi_pita_hoon_remix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bidi_pita_hoon_remixSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aatiSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aati);

        final Button maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aati = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aati);

        maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aati.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                maza_aata_raat_mein_nind_aatiSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankarSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankar);

        final Button aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankar = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankar);

        aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aise_hota_hai_bohot_bhayankarSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer try_karke_dekhiyeSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.try_karke_dekhiye);

        final Button try_karke_dekhiye = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.try_karke_dekhiye);

        try_karke_dekhiye.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try_karke_dekhiyeSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ultiSoundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ulti);

        final Button nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ulti = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ulti);

        nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ulti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nahi_piyunga_na_toh_khoon_ki_ultiSoundMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });







    }
}
```

Comment: That's good. So do it.

Comment: I need help, don't know how to do it.

Comment: do you need separate start buttons or also a common start button? Accordingly the answer may vary.

Comment: I have 18 buttons to start 18 playbacks, but i need one more button to stop all of them!

Comment: Please stop reverting my changes, your tags were invalid